# Play store error: can't install app try again, and it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix the problem

Tags: google-play, google-contacts-api

Ive released a new app on the play store yesterday and it was published. However when I try to download and install it shows this error: can't install app X try again, and it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix the problem.

I've tried to clear play store cache, data, reset the phone several times.
Tried on my Xiami Redmi note 5, also tried on another redmi not 7. Same error happens.

PS: I know that the app is working because installing it through Android Studio works perfectly fine. However when uploading to Play Store and trying to download it does not work. Also I've saw that after I've generated the APK file, it does not work. Ive tried to install using the APK file and it showed: "App was not installed"

Comment: I'm not sure what help you expect us to provide when you can't install your own application. We have no access to your application, the device you're attempting to install it on, your Play Store account, or any other means of troubleshooting the issue. if it's not installing on any device, then apparently there's an issue with the application itself, that clearly we can't help with as we don't have access to your code. There's also no specific question in your post, as *Can you help me to install my own program?* isn't a programming question.

Comment: hi Ken, thanks for you comment, but apparently there is a problem related to the APK file (made through AS) file because it's said that I do can install it using Android Studio and its working perfectly fine

Comment: Yeah, the APK file would be *the application itself*. Again, not sure what you expect us to do.

Comment: I understand but why installing the app using Play button on Android Studio works? Is there any difference between the play button version and the generated signed apk version? Because one works, the other does not...

Answer (score 1):

Ive ended up solving my problem by removing this line of code on the maniffest file:

```
android:protectionLevel="signature"
```

So sad that Google dont have a report to debug this problem... I had a lot of trouble to find it.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of failed attempts from last 3 days. Today, I figured out that the problem affecting my Android App Version Update – *Can't Install Error Message* was to change:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-R'
buildToolsVersion '30.0.0 rc4'
targetSdkVersion 30
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Now it is working on GooglePlay. Hope it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem some weeks ago and in my case the app wasn't installing for only Android 9.0 (pie) but installed on other devices.

After lots of sleepless nights I discovered that I was replacing an existing attribute from the manifest merger using the **tools:replace** attribute but I was specifying an empty string value to the replaced attribute.

Which in my case was the **appComponentFactory** attribute.

So if you have these lines of code or anything similar in your manifest, remove them completely or specify an actual value for the attribute you're replacing.

`<application
. 
tools:replace="appComponentFactory" 
android:appComponentFactory=" " >
. 
. 
</application>`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because I paused the testing track on Google Play Console. I thought would only pause the current track, and I thought when I upload a new release that one would be open. It took me time to notice it. Because it passed 1 month since the last test.

So, if someone is suffering from this problem, please check whether the track you are releasing is open or paused.