# My publish app can not be installed on two devices with no error code

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

One of the users with a note 10 plus and one with s9 are receiving "can't install app". 
What's weird is that no error code is displayed and other apps can still be installed, so I don't think the issue is google play.

My app's target sdk is 28, and it's being installed on android 9 and 10 operated devices

```
  android {
          compileSdkVersion 28
          buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.ex.app'
    targetSdkVersion 28
    minSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 214
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "app-4.9.1")

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

flavorDimensions "default"
```

[image: Error in question]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is
Error retrieving information from the server.

**Solution**

Go to Settings > Apps > All > Google Play Store and select both Clear data and Clear cache. Do the same for the Google Services Framework.

Comment: It still not working, there is really nothing that I can do from the app at this stage ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing protectionlevel=signature in android manifest fixed the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570714/8939897